# chef deploy start service and restart service in sequence

Tags: chef, chef-solo

[Chef stop and start service in sequence](https://serverfault.com/questions/378520/chef-stop-and-start-service-in-sequence) and would like to ask different procedure.

Step 1: framework bootstrap to jboss service

```
bash "bootstrap application" do
    code <<-EOF
    ant bootstrap
    EOF
end
```

Step 2: then start jboss

```
service "jboss" do
    action :start
end
```

Step 3: install application

```
bash "install application" do
    code <<-EOF
    ant install
    EOF
end
```

in between step 2 and 3, ant install returns error because jboss is not started yet. but successful on the 2nd run. obviously step 3 doesnt know if the jboss already started.

how to do this on chef?

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled on this by mistake but it looks like a similar issue I had with rundeck... is your service starting but not started?

Try testing this

```
service "jboss" do
    start_command 'service jboss start && sleep 30'
    action :start
end
```

For rundeck it was the restart I had issues with and used curl to probe it until it was up.

```
service 'rundeckd' do
  restart_command 'service rundeckd restart && RETRIES=0 && until curl localhost:4440 || [ $RETRIES -eq 30 ]; do (( RETRIES++ )); sleep 5; done'
  action :start
end
```

```

Answer (score 0):

Use [resource subscription](http://docs.opscode.com/chef/resources.html#subscribes-syntax) to maintain execution order.

Use `retries` to make sure application installation works, and you can run resource `bash[install application]` at the end of chef runs via `subscribes :run, "service[jboss]", :delayed`

```
bash "install application" do
  code <<-EOF
  ant install
  EOF
  action :nothing
  retries 3
  subscribes :run, "service[jboss]", :delayed 
end
```

Comment: checking this one.. got two versions, 1st using ruby_block and this one. will keep you posted thanks

Comment: hmm.. that didnt do it. jboss didnt start.

Comment: what about the resource "bash[bootstrap application]"? you can't start jboss if bootstrap fails.

Comment: This is the official way to do things, using `notifies` or `subscribes`, but the trouble with many Java (and other) services is their wrapper returns "SUCCESS" immediately, even though the actual initialization of the process takes another minute (or few). The hard sleep of another answer is one way to test, though the curl/wget probe of the expected open port can be a better and more surefire way to ensure any web/network services are fully started before moving on.